# Relation between Spring @Transactional and Camel Transacted

Tags: apache-camel, spring-transactions, spring-camel

If the camel DSL is marked as transacted(), then do we really need to put @Transactional annotation in Spring service method ?

I really want to know In and Out of Camel and Spring Transaction interaction.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to know Camel transactions in depth I highly recommend [Camel in Action 2nd edition](https://www.manning.com/books/camel-in-action-second-edition).

Comment: Yeah for in-depth then there is an entire chapter on transactions in that book, that is 35+ pages long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR

no, generally **you do not need to annotate any method `@Transactional` to make Camel transactions work**.

The main interaction between Camel and Spring TransactionManager is that Camel delegates transaction handling to Spring txManager if it is configured to do so. In other words: Camel uses the Spring txManager if it is available, but you can use other txManagers as well.

For this delegation no `@Transactional` annotations are needed. Instead you have to configure Spring txManager and mark the Camel route as `transacted()`.

#### The long story

However, your question leaves room for assumptions. What method do you want to annotate `@Transactional`? The method that contains the route? A method of a managed bean that is called by the route? A method totally independent of the Camel route?

A transacted [Camel route](http://camel.apache.org/routes.html) creates a transaction scope around the whole route (1) or more specific the [unit of work](http://camel.apache.org/oncompletion.html).

Let's take an example: a route that reads from a JMS queue, transforms the data and writes to multiple other JMS queues. If you mark the route transacted and an error occurs while sending the last message, the transaction is rolled back and no messages are sent.

Thanks to the transaction scope, the already "sent" (outgoing) messages are not committed until the transaction completes successfully. After the rollback, the same message (incoming) is redelivered by the broker and processed again by the route.

Notice that a Camel route **can** be transacted without the `transacted()` marker (2) in the route.

However, since Camel is about integration you often have "mixed environments", such as JMS to database. Or even worse, you do HTTP requests during the route. If an error occurs later, you cannot "undo" these calls.

Therefore, in the world of Camel, transactions can help a lot, but often they are not enough. You have to **implement compensations** to be able to really roll back an aborted route processing.

If you use transacted routes, be sure to write [Route tests](http://camel.apache.org/testing.html) who simulate errors in route processing and check if rollback works as you expect it.

Well, these are some high-level thoughts about Camel and transactions. If you want to dive deeper, get the Camel book I recommended in the comments :-)

**Footnotes:**

(1) When the route contains stateful components or EIPs (for example [aggregator](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html), [resequencer](http://camel.apache.org/resequencer.html) etc), they introduce transaction boundaries inside the Camel route. In such cases, the transaction scope ends at the first stateful component. As a consequence, these components typically offer an optional persistence to offer a possibility to save the state.

To make such transaction boundaries explicit, I typically do not continue in the same route after such a component, but create a new one and send the result message of the stateful component to the new route.

(2) For example with a JMS consumer that uses JMS local transactions.