# Listen JMS message via Apache Camel

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, jms

I want to create Apache Camel + Spring Boot app with next logic. My route should parse some xml-document and foreach element in it do next:

- Check some condition
- Send message to Artemis Queue
- Wait for response
- Process it
- Continue loop

### Right now my code looks like next

```
public void route() {
       from()
       .loopDoWhile(<some condition>)
                           .choice()
                               .when(<process>)
                               .marshal(documentPropertiesRequest)
                               .process(exchange -> {
                                   ProducerTemplate producer = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();
                                   var endpoint = exchange.getContext().getEndpoint("jms:queue:{{queues.get-document-properties}}");
                                   producer.setDefaultEndpoint(endpoint);
                                   producer.sendBody(endpoint,exchange);

                                   ConsumerTemplate template = exchange.getContext().createConsumerTemplate();
                                   var response = template.receiveBody("jms:queue:{{queues.get-document-properties-response}}",
   3600);
                                   if (response == null) throw new ExchangeTimedOutException(exchange, 3600, "Server didn't respond in
   time");
                                   exchange.getIn().setBody(response);
                               })
                               .unmarshal(documentPropertiesResponse)
                               .process(new HandleDocumentPropertiesProcessor()) }
```

Also I have some mock to test 3rd party service response here:

```
from("jms:queue:{{queues.get-document-properties}}")
                .routeId("mock")
                .log("Get properties request")
                .unmarshal(documentPropertiesRequest)
                .process(<some process>)
                .marshal(documentPropertiesResponse)
                .toD("jms:queue:{{queues.get-document-properties}}");
```

When I send a message to start queue evverything works fine before it reaches ProducerTemplate part. Message sends but doesn't appear in mock route (i tried to send message there directly and everything was fine) and my consumer is unable to consume something.

Other than that i tried next options:

- Simple route with inOut strategy - didn't work because it doesn't work with transacations.
- Split on two routes, one sends and one recieves. - didn't work because i want to update the same message in loop.

Well, where could a problem be or what other solutions i didn't see?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although not explicitly specified in the code, it seems your route is transacted. Compare to https://stackoverflow.com/a/55397379/13860684 (Footnote 2). When the route is transacted, then all the messages you sent won't be visible to the consumer until the route is completed. I think you may have to re-think your design from a transactional perspective.

Comment: I read about transactions and it really seems like messages in a whole route (incuding loop) won't be sent until the transaction will be commited.  Right now my plan is to use non-camel connection to avoid transactions.